# Prove that the tangent line to the graph of f at $(a, \sqrt{1-a^2})$ intersects the graph only at that point

Tags: derivatives

For $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.   $-1<x<1$,

Prove that the tangent line to the graph of f at $(a, \sqrt{1-a^2} )$ intersects the graph only at that point. (Use differentiation knowledge to finish the proof)

My first intuition is that I should suppose tangent line intersects the graph at two points and find a contradiction. But, I have no idea how to connect tangent line to differentiation. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: what is the´Problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $f'(x)=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$ and we find
$$y=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}x+n$$ now compute $n$

Comment: typo in the sign?

Comment: That makes sense! I think I know how to continue!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

this is the tangent line to the point of abscissa $a$ of the semi-circle of center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$, so it has this unique common point with the circle.

Comment: Squaring $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ you have the equation $y^2+x^2=1$ that is the circle of radius $1$ that, for $y>0$ is the semicircle